# Why is ping resolving to an IP 198.105.254.228 for any random hostname that i type?

Tags: ubuntu, hostname, vagrant

I have a `precise32` (ubuntu 12.04) vagrant vm running on my system.
If i try to ping a random string, eg `ping "thisip.doesnot"` it resolves to an IP `198.105.254.228` . This is try for any other random string i put in. Why does this happen?
How can i change this behaviour and make it respond "ping: unknown host thisip.doesnot"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because your ISP is hijacking your DNS queries.

They are trying to be "helpful" by redirecting requests for nonexistent domains to [a white label service](http://www.dnsrsearch.com/) that provides search results and advertising, from which everyone but you gets a cut of the revenue.

Fortunately they do have a [preferences page](http://www.dnsrsearch.com/prefs.php) where you can supposedly turn it off.

Comment: take a look at this article:  http://www.howtogeek.com/167239/7-reasons-to-use-a-third-party-dns-service/

Comment: This infuriates me, as much as the ads on [unnamed ISP]'s webmail page.  I pay too much for this ISP as it is.  I had even specified one of the free public DNS servers from Google (8.8.8.8) as my primary and relegated the ISP's DNS to secondary.  However, the result is the same:  primary fails to resolve, so your system tries the secondary, which instead of returning error & failing the request (as a DNS should), returns the IP address of the ad site.  This particular ISP, despite being huge, must be getting desperate... or just greedy!